# Phone to replace OP3T without regressions

Tags: android, smartphones

I'm looking to replace my OnePlus 3T that got some damage to the screen. I tried narrowing down my choices on a site that allows filtering based on hardware requirements, but ended up with zero matches. So I'm looking for something that is as close as can be found.

Requirements:

- Android
- New enough to get at least a couple of years of security updates from the vendor
- Dual SIM
- Headphone jack
- OLED screen that is not much smaller
- No larger in body width/height

Price is not very important. It would be nice not to regress in battery life, charging speed or other hardware specs, but I could live with a small downgrade.

Comment: Can you specify the screen size?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths, ~5.5"